# Removing table cell borders CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm making an events calendar on a website for a class. The top row of the calendar is the days of the week and the next 4 are the calendar days. The calendar day cells have borders but the days of the week in row one do not. I can't figure out how to get rid of the borders in the 1st row. I tried changing the border color. I tried border="0px" in various places. Can anyone help?

I'm new at HTML and CSS so if you need any information let me know.

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS in your question please.

Comment: try adding `tr:first-child td {border: 0}` at the end of your css-file

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what your are looking for. Idea is to have same color as th background and border.

[jsffiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxgd8/)

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding:5px;
}
td,th {
   border:1px solid #ccc;
}

th {
    background-color:#333;
    border:1px solid #333;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `border-collapse:collapse;` property like

```
tr:first-child td,tr:first-child th
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp) for better understanding.

Comment: Or if you feel professional enough and you want an indepth understanding and you care for your knowledge - just read from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse